# Get information and attributes from other gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is it possible to get information, such as the block attributes, from other blocks from within a registerBlockType call?

E.g. if I have a block with InnerBlocks as the content, is it possible to get attributes from the blocks inside that InnerBlocks, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you manages your own store inside Gutenberg which is actually a Redux store. [@wordpress/data](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/packages/packages-data/)

It is recommended to keep logic of your multiple blocks separately in their own attributes (that's why they are blocks). For re-usability purpose you can make React components which can be used inside different blocks, in this way attributes of your block can be passed to the props of React Component.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Block context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/) to achieve this.

In your parent block, map the attribute you want to use in your child block using `providesContext`. So if you would like to map the `recordId` property, your parent block configuration would look like this:

```js
registerBlockType('my-plugin/parent-block', {
  // ...

  attributes: {
    recordId: {
      type: 'number',
    },
  },
 
  providesContext: {
    'my-plugin/recordId': 'recordId',
  },

  // ...
}
```

The child block can then "consume" the context by adding the following `useContext` line to your child block configuration:

```js
registerBlockType('my-plugin/child-block', {
  // ...

  usesContext: ['my-plugin/recordId'],

  // ...
}
```

In your child block's `edit` and `save` methods, you can then access the context like this:

```js
registerBlockType('my-plugin/child-block', {
  // ...

  edit(props) {
    const { context } = props;
    const { "my-plugin/recordId": recordId } = context;

    return (
      <p>{ recordId }</p>
    );
  },

  save(props) {
    const { context } = props;
    const { "my-plugin/recordId": recordId } = context;

    return (
      <p>{ recordId }</p>
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```